# Pods topology not working in multiple availability zone

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, topology

```
topologySpreadConstraints:
        - maxSkew: 1
          topologyKey: "topology.kubernetes.io/zone"
          whenUnsatisfiable: DoNotSchedule
          labelSelector:
            matchLabels:
              app: license-v1
```

this is my pod topology mentioned in YML file

I have 6 instances 3 in 1a and 3 in 1b

as soon as I apply the above YAML file, In my understanding both PODs should be created in nodes from different zones.

```
NAME       READY  STATUS    RESTARTS  AGE     IP        NODE                          NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
app-pod-1  1/1    Running   0         4m48s   *.*.*.*   ip-*.*-233-140.eu-central-1   <none>           <none>
app-pod-2  1/1    Running   0         4m51s   *.*.*.*   ip-*.*-233-140.eu-central-1   <none>           <none>
```

Comment: Can you share your complete`deployment` yaml file. The above constraints work just fine for me. 2 pods are scheduled on nodes in separate AZ, 3rd one goes into `Pending`.